# How to create HashMap dynamically

Tags: java

I have `.txt` file with 5L values(Lines) in the following way and also have partition size `50000`.

```
 1
 3
-1546.9
-67.90
3456
.
.
.
```

With the following example you can understand what is mean by Partition in my point of view.

after importing file data into list we can see in the following way.

```
 importingdata={1,2,3,4,5,.........500000};
```

After partition, you can see in the following way.

```
PartitionList={{1,2,3,...50000},{50001,....,100000},{100001,......,150000},...{450000,.....500000}};
```

partitionList datatype is `ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,Double>>`.it means all sub-lists of partitionlist was `HashMap<Integer,Double>`.

All `HashMap` lists starts their key values from `1 to 50000`.like in the following way.

```
     PartitionList={{1->1,2->2,3->3,...,50000->50000},{1->50001,.....,50000->100000},{1->100001,....,50000->150000},...,{1->450000,.....,50000->500000}};
```

I want to arrange file data in the above way while file importing time.

for this I tried with sample code but it's not working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Double>> finalList=new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<Integer, Double> hash1=new HashMap<>();
    hash1.put(1, 1.0);
    hash1.put(2, 2.0);
    hash1.put(3, 3.0);
    finalList.add(hash1);
    System.out.println(finalList.size());
    System.out.println(hash1.size());
    hash1.clear();
    System.out.println(hash1.size());
    hash1.put(1, 1.0);
    hash1.put(2, 2.0);
    hash1.put(3, 3.0);
    finalList.add(hash1);
    System.out.println(finalList.size());
    System.out.println(hash1.size());
    hash1.clear();
    System.out.println(hash1.size());
    HashMap<Integer, Double> hash2=finalList.get(1);
    HashMap<Integer, Double> hash3=finalList.get(2);
    System.out.println(hash2.size());
    System.out.println(hash3.size());
}
```

I hope,you guys understand what I am trying.
Here I mention `5L` lines, but in my real case I am dealing with `80L` So suggest me with optimized code.

Thanks

Comment: **Lakh is still not an SI unit**. Please keep that in mind!

To everyone not knowing what the L means: **100000**.

Comment: @ppeterka66 I will mention clearly.

Comment: You're adding the same HashSet *reference* over and over to your list.  If you want to have different sets at the same time, you need to instantiate more than one.

Comment: @Sebastian How can I create instantiate dynamically.

Comment: @Hanumath I answered the question zou asked Sebastian 12 minutes ago...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HashMap is mutable!** The hashMap references are still the same. When you do this:

```
hash1.clear();
```

You clear **the original** map instance. This means, the map instance you put into the list gets cleared.

You should do

```
hash1 = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
```

instead. This updates the variable's reference to a *new instance* of HashMap().

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's working great.Can you tell me What I am following is it efficient way for partitioning list.

Comment: @Hanumath Well, as always: it depends. I'd try to leave out the Map: it adds a lot of overhead in every aspect. If the number of elements is known before the processing, and the, I'd go with one huge array. If nőt, then a single List, and if you want to partition the load, you can always do it with the subList() method. I'd éven start thinking about changing the processing logic tó deal with chunks of the input rather than áll of the data át once...

Comment: @ppeterka66 I would suggest using the guava collections2 api methods to partition the list instead of reinventing the wheel by using subList(). Because with sublist you will have to handle the code for start and end index. Lets just offload the headache to guava.:-)

Comment: @Pratik Thanks for the comment, anyhting that makes code easier and readable is good. I never felt that it is a burden to handle that, and never tried to search for an easier way - but I began programming in C, so Java always felt like a convenient and smooth thing compared to the struct-malloc-pointer-free hell...

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map<Integer, Double>> finalList=new ArrayList<Map<Integer, Double>>();
    Map<Integer, Double> hash1=new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
    hash1.put(1, 1.0);
    hash1.put(2, 2.0);
    hash1.put(3, 3.0);
    finalList.add(hash1);
    System.out.println(finalList.size());
    System.out.println(hash1.size());
    hash1 = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
    System.out.println(hash1.size());
    hash1.put(1, 1.0);
    hash1.put(2, 2.0);
    hash1.put(3, 3.0);
    finalList.add(hash1);
    System.out.println(finalList.size());
    System.out.println(hash1.size());
    // and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your sample code.

1. You need to create new instances of the hashmap once you have added the 50000 entries into it. Calling clear shall not help your case.
2. Since you are well aware of the size of the HashMap while creating the hashmap make sure to pass the initial size. Providing the initial size prevents frequent rehashing which affects the performance

> `HashMap<Integer, Double> hash1=new HashMap<Integer,Double>(50000);`

1. I am not aware if its a typo or not. In the sample code you you are trying to call get(1) whereas list indices start from 0 and not from 1.

For your actual problem you should have a look at Google Collections2 API. Please find below a code which will help you achieve your final goal

```
// Read all 80Lac lines
    List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(
            new File("d:/input.txt").toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset());       

    // Partition the 80L records into lists of 50000
    List<List<String>> partitionedLists = Lists.partition(allLines, 50000);

    ArrayList<ListMultimap<Integer, String>> finalList = new ArrayList<ListMultimap<Integer,String>>();
    for(final List<String> item: partitionedLists){         
        ListMultimap<Integer, String> finalMap = Multimaps.index(item.iterator(), new Function<String,Integer>(){               
            @Override
            public Integer apply(String arg0) {
                return item.indexOf(arg0);                                  
            }

        });

        finalList.add(finalMap);
    }
```

Even I am new to the Collections API but I tested the above code it does create a list of maps with key as the index. Only issue is that MultiMaps are normally used to achieve GROUP BY kind of operation and hence duplicate values are getting grouped together. I am working on it but meanwhile you can start your implementation using the above code.

Comment: Just to add you need to have Java 7 for the above sample to work. Since I have used the Files api